# How to include Password Strength Validator in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

i am struggle days to find a way for working password strength checker, but still not found solution. I have AjaxBeginForm in partial view for some simple input.

Here is my view:
    @model EntryViewModel

```
<style>
input.input-validation-error,
textarea.input-validation-error,
select.input-validation-error {
    background: #FEF1EC;
    border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
}
.field-validation-error {
    color: #C55050;
}
</style>


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Entry", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Url)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Url, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Url)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryId)

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
        <input class=" btn btn-primary" id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Create" />
    </div>
}
```

I've tried with many methods, including KendoUI, but none of works. Any suggestions for solution?

Comment: Take a look at these jquery solutions: http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-password-strength.html

Answer (score 1):

What about the [Google Password Strength API?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19245/Google-Password-Strength-API).

Answer (score 1):

what about StringLength and DataType(DataType.Password)

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }    

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Pass \"{0}\" must have no less {2} chars.", MinimumLength = 8)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webappers.com/2007/08/22/jquery-password-strength-meter-with-better-algorithm/

I had once implemented using this 
hope this helps you. :)